# UpdateWithChildren not updating Lists (OneToMany) relationships

Tags: sqlite-net-extensions

Here is some sample code to reproduce the problem:

**Customer class**

```
public class Customer
{
    private int _id;

    [Column("_id"), PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {_id = value;}
        }
    }

   private string _name;

   [Column("_name")]
   public string Name
   {
       get { return _name; }
       set
       {
           if (value != _name)
           {_name = value;}
       }
   }

   private List<Order> _orders;
   [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert | CascadeOperation.CascadeRead | CascadeOperation.CascadeDelete)]
   public List<Order> Orders
   {
       get { return _orders; }
       set
       {
           if (_orders != value)
           {
               _orders = value;
           }
       }
   }
```

**Order class**

```
public class Order
{
    private int _id;

    [Column("_id"), PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
                _id = value;
        }
    }

    private string _name;

    [Column("_name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
                _name = value;
        }
    }

    private int _customerId;

    [Column("_customerId"), ForeignKey(typeof(Customer))]
    public int CustomerId
    {
        get { return _customerId; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _customerId)
                _customerId = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**DB operations**

```
Customer customer = new Customer(){Name = "Customer One"};
context.InsertWithChildren(customer, true);
customer.Orders = new List<Order>();
customer.Orders.Add(new Order(){Name="Sample order"});
context.UpdateWithChildren(customer);

// get a new copy from the db
var result = context.GetWithChildren<Customer>(customer.Id,true); 

List<Order> orders = result.Orders; // Orders.Count is 0
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is `UpdateWithChildren` supposed to work like this?

**EDIT**

Looks like `UpdateWithChildren` does not insert a new `Order`if one is not present in the DB. Inserting the order first, assigning it to the customer and then calling `UpdateWithChildren` establishes the relationship.

```
Customer customer = new Customer(){Name = "Customer One"};
context.InsertWithChildren(customer, true);

List<Order> newOrders = new List<Order>();
newOrders.Add(new Order(){Name="Test order"});
context.InsertAllWithChildren(newOrders,true);

customer.Orders = newOrders;

context.UpdateWithChildren(customer);

var result = context.GetWithChildren<Customer>(customer.Id,true);

List<Order> orders = result.Orders; // Orders.Count is 1
```

I assume this is how I am supposed to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already noticed `UpdateWithChildren` doesn't insert any new objects into the database. It just updates the relationships. If you want to Insert or Update objects you can use `InsertOrReplaceWithChildren` or Insert first the objects and then update the relationships.

Alternatively you can use recursive insert operations:

```
Customer customer = new Customer(){
    Name = "Customer One",
    Orders = new List<Order>{ new Order(){ Name="Test order" } }
};

// Recursively insert 'customer' and all its orders
context.InsertWithChildren(customer, true);
```

Comment: is there any reason why you haven't added such functionality yet? (if UpdateWithChildren does not find the children in the DB, insert them then?) InsertOrReplace is ok but it wipes out everything first and then writes everything again which causes performance issues.

Comment: SQLite-Net Extensions is not a fully featured ORM and doesn't keep track of modified or inserted objects. It's the user duty to keep track of these changes, so an `UpdateWithChildren` that inserts the objects into the database will perform the very same operations that `InsertOrReplaceWithChildren`.